# Save button missing from Drupal site

Tags: drupal, button, save

I'm in the middle of creating a Drupal site. It already has lots of content. This morning I found out that the "Save" button has now gone missing from my Page and News nodes. Users now have to click Preview before the Save button appears (both for creating new content and editing existing content). It was fine yesterday and I'm not sure what has changed. Can anyone help me to restore the Save button?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check under `admin/content/node-settings` if you set the preview to "required", that would cause this behaviour. You can also try to emtpy all caches.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you so much. It fixed it straight away. I hadn't seen the menu item for Post Settings!

Answer (score 0):

in Drupal 8 , preview mode can be set for each content types,e.g for articles :

> ```
>  /admin/structure/types/manage/article
> ```

If set to required the save button will appear only after previewing the content and returning to edit mode.